# Android Parse Local Datastore Returns Empty

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have been working on an application where you input childs names and ages, and specific data is shown according to there input. I store the child info inside a local datastore.

Take a look at this simple class made for simple storage: `public class

```js
ChildInfo {

    public String name;
    public String gradeLevel;
    public int gradeLevelInt;

    public ChildInfo() {

    }
    public ChildInfo(String _name, String _gradeLevel, int _gradeLevelInt) {
        gradeLevel = _gradeLevel;
        name = _name;
    }
}
```

Inside my main fragment I have a list of ChildInfo Classes named **children**.

I call them like so:

```js
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Child");
        query.fromLocalDatastore();
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    children.clear(); //Clear it out before we regen every person!
                    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                        ChildInfo child = new ChildInfo();
                        child.name = objects.get(i).getString("Name");
                        child.gradeLevel = objects.get(i).getString("GradeLevel");
                        child.gradeLevelInt = objects.get(i).getInt("GradeLevelInt");
                        children.add(child);
                    }
                    for (int i = pagerAdapter.getCount() - 1; i > 0; i--){ pagerAdapter.removeView(pager, i); } //Removes all pages.
                } else {
                    Log.e("HomeScreen", e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

> The Question

This code WORKS, **half the time**. When I execute the query in the onViewCreated method it will return nothing. `object.size` is zero, but when called in the onResume method after I enter another page and exit back to this fragment it WILL work. Any ideas? I think this might be a bug with the parse API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I found the fix! For some reason the children list lost everything added to it once it left the done method. I re arranged the code and this is the new Parse.com Query

```css
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Child");
        query.fromLocalDatastore();
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    removeAllViews(pager);
                    children.clear(); //Clear it out before we regen every person!
                    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                        ChildInfo child = new ChildInfo();
                        child.name = objects.get(i).getString("Name");
                        child.gradeLevel = objects.get(i).getString("GradeLevel");
                        child.gradeLevelInt = objects.get(i).getInt("GradeLevelInt");
                        children.add(child);
                    }
                    Log.i("HomePagerAdapter", "Children Size: " + children.size() + "\n     Obj Size: " + objects.size());
                    for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
                        addChild(pager, children.get(i).name, children.get(i).gradeLevelInt);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("HomePagerAdapter", e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```